# Is it possible to get a material which yellow in normal light and doesn't reflect spectral yellow?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, vision

Imagine an object which reflects only green and red spectral colors. In normal light, it should appear yellow. But when we light up this object by spectral yellow color, it should appear dark, because it can't reflect spectral yellow.

Are there any examples of this behavior in real live? This  is quite similar to this question [Yellow color, but not really - does it reflect pure yellow light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461588/yellow-color-but-not-really-does-it-reflect-pure-yellow-light), but I'm asking for "real world" examples and test cases.

Comment: maybe this answer of mine will help clear the concepts https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/552840/what-determines-whether-colors-you-cant-see-are-visible-or-not/552878#552878

Comment: @annav sorry if my question is not clear. I am not asking for explanation but examples where we can observe this behavior